# Decision Tree Classifier outputs "Male" if true and "Male" if false?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am working with a decision tree classifier to try and predict Male or Female based on a genre of a show.  Once I visualize the decision tree using graphviz, the graph outputs Male as True and False.  I am having trouble with this issue.

There is a possibility that it is not my code that is wrong but maybe my feature and target variables. 
Here is the code that is in the jupyter notebook block:

```
Male = tmp[tmp['gender'] == 'M']
Female = tmp[tmp['gender'] == 'F' ]
X = tmp.loc[:, ['Fantasy', 'Romance']]
# 'Cars', 'Drama', 'Game','SliceofLife','Music', 'Psychological', 'Fantasy', 'Horror','Historical','Space','Sci-Fi', 'Magic', 'Adventure', 'Samurai', 'ShounenAi', 'Mecha', 'Thriller', 'Demons', 'Kids', 'Romance', 'Sports', 'Seinen', 'School', 'ShoujoAi', 'Comedy']]
y = tmp['gender']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

model_dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier() 
model_dtc = model_dtc.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model_dtc.predict(X_test)

df_dtc = pd.DataFrame({'Actual': y_test, 'Predicted': y_pred})  

tree.export_graphviz(model_dtc, out_file='gender_classifier.dot', feature_names=['Fantasy', 'Romance'],class_names=tmp['gender'] ,filled=True, rounded=True,special_characters=True)

dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(model_dtc, out_file=None, feature_names = ['Fantasy','Romance'], class_names = tmp['gender'] , filled=True, rounded=True, special_characters=True)
graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data)
graph
```

graphviz output
[image: graphviz output]

Any thoughts or suggestions would be extremely helpful!

Comment: why is your image (tree) doesnot have a female class ?

Comment: Please show a sample of your training data `X` & `y` - it is not clear indeed that class `Female` is present...

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is not the complete tree. Are you saying the predict method always has the output Male?

From the graph I have made a couple of observations:

1. Maybe I am wrong on this one, but if your data has two classes then the *value* array in the graph should only contain 2 vals, I see three.
2. You have not set any max_depth parameter have you? If not then the tree should expand until the nodes are pure which is not the case here.

Maybe try converting it to a png ?
Use this -
`dot -Tpng tree.dot -o tree.png`